# Java Selenium- list of elements are empty but I see during the test that it's not

Tags: java, css, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, salesforce

I'm trying to automate some processes in Salesforce.
I'm using Java Selenium in IntelliJ.

During the test, I try to find a list of elements and I want to choose one of them by using get(index).
The problem is that during the run/debug, I see that it returns size = 0, which indicates the list is empty.
However, when I inspect the element I'm trying to get *during the test* I see that the selector I've used indeed find the list of elements. How is it possible?
As far as I know, it can't be a wait issue because I saw this during debugging.

Here is the code:

```
public void changeOwner() {
    waiting(5000);
    List<WebElement> ownerBtns = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[title='Change Owner']     [type='button'][part='button button-icon']"));
    System.out.println("The size of the list is " + ownerBtns.size());
    WebElement desiredOwnerBtn = ownerBtns.get(0);
    click(desiredOwnerBtn);
    click(changeOwnerBtn);
    waiting(2000);
    fillText(searchOwnerField, "Yonatan Bashiri");
    for (WebElement owner : listOfOwners) {
        if (getText(owner).equals("Yonatan Bashiri")) {
            click(owner);
            break;
        }
    }
    click(changeOwnerBtn);
    waiting(2000);
}
```

The problematic list is ownerBtns
In the debugger is says ownerBtns = (ArrayList@6835) size = 0
If I put this selector: [title='Change Owner'][type='button'][part='button button-icon'] in the devtools during the test I find 3 elements.

Thank you for the help

Comment: Check if the desired elements are within an `IFRAME`, if yes, you need to switch into the `IFRAME` and then locate elements.